# Delete entire terminal history wherever it is stored in a LAN

Tags: linux, terminal

In our lab, local area network where a student can log into any system with their id and password. I want to delete my terminal command history in my terminal and wherever it might be stored elsewhere. I have tried `history -c` which deletes the terminal history in the current computer and not on any other computers. Is there any command to delete the entire terminal history of a user on all computers and from the supervisors system without needing the root password? We are using red hat distro linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are looking for the history stored by the `shell` you are using in those terminals (which are terminal emulators, I assume).

Typically in a Linux system that is the `bash` shell these days, though you will have to check for your installation and profile.

For the example of a `bash` shell you will have to empty the file `~/.bash_history`. That is a hidden file in your personal home folder that is used by the shell. Other shells use other locations. In case of a lab setup your home folder typically is maintained in some central server system and mounted from there to some local system you might work on. That is why deleting the content once typically has effect elsewhere.

Note however that you may have a different setup locally. So first you will have to find out that setup.

Comment: When i try to access the ~/.bash_history file, i'm getting a permission denied message. Any way around this?

Comment: That is odd, since your own processes (your current shell) has to be able to write the entries in the history. What are the exact permissions and the exact location? Maybe you got the wrong file?

Comment: In the lab, when i login i see a folder called home. But when i login through a putty terminal, i can neither access nor see the home folder when i type the ls command.

Comment: This is not so much about what folder you "see", but what folder is actually used by your system to load stuff like profile settings. That is what I meant with "you have to find out". You'd have to check the general profile settings (typically found in `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d`) which take care to load certain resource files for a login and an ordinary shell you start. Also the absolute paths to those files may be of interest, since they may actually point to folders other than your local home folder.